# SQL Server command not showing result

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to create some text but the text is not showing up...

Here is my code:

```
SqlCommand getLeastId = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id FROM [Chat-main] WHERE Userid LIKE @id AND Sendtoid LIKE @toid", c);

getLeastId.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", (string)Session["CurentUserid"]);
getLeastId.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toid", (string)Session["contactuserid"]);

c.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = getLeastId.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
    while (reader.Read())
        CreateDiv((int)reader[0]);

c.Close();
```

The create div function is working.

Thank you guys for helping

My table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Chat-main] 
(
    [Id]       INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [tag]      VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    [commet]   VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Userid]   VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Sendtoid] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: The way you are passing parameters for LIKE operation is not correct. First you need to decide you really need to use LIKE operator to query the data? Based on the columns you are comparing I think you should be using `=` operator.

Comment: Side note: You really want to reduce your use of `varchar(max)`. It's perfectly valid to limit the user names to 10, 20 chars max, as well as to limit the chat message length. Limiting user ids to `varchar(10)` and `commet` (I'm guessing should be `comment`) length to, say, 4000, even 8000 would be a much better design and could also improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your code.

1- `LIKE` can't be used with `integer`, it is only meant for string types. If you still want, you can use it by converting `INT` to `VARCHAR` like following.

```
 CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(9)) LIKE '%123'
```

2- `LIKE` used for `Sendtoid` is also not correct, it should be like following.

```
 getLeastId.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toid"
 , "%" +  (string)Session["contactuserid"] + "%");
```

You can change your code like following.

```
 SqlCommand getLeastId = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id FROM [Chat-main] Where Userid = @id AND Sendtoid like @toid", c);
            getLeastId.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", (string)Session["CurentUserid"]);
            getLeastId.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toid", "%" + (string)Session["contactuserid"] + "%");
            c.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = getLeastId.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
                while (reader.Read())
                    CreateDiv((int)reader[0]);
            c.Close();
```